# When one is not 고수

Tags: word-choice, translation

When somebody is very good at something (e.g. a video game, a musical instrument) they may be called 고수.

Examples:

- 가라테 **고수가** 한 남자를 구타해서 죽였다. A karate **master** beat a man to death.
- 그리고 학생이 **고수가** 돼. Thus, the student becomes the **master**.
- [2:2 한국인 vs 외국인 슈퍼 고수 매치 2경기](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acJWk6blveg)  2:2 Korean vs Foreigner Super *Gosu* Match, second game

What words are typically used to describe situations of not being 고수? For example, what do we call somebody that tries very hard, but doesn't do so well. What is a n00b (초보자)?

Comment: BTW, your second example "그리고 학생이 고수가 돼", sounds like you're talking about, say, a high school student who practices for months to become a master taekwondo/go/starcraft player.  Note that 학생 usually means a school student, while the original English sentence most likely means "someone who is learning."

Comment: Related: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=gosu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**고수** : expert
**중수**(joong soo) : intermediate
**하수**(ha soo) : beginner

However, in the same way, **초보**(chobo) is typically more used as **Ha Soo**

**고/중/하** mean high/mid/low. **수** means a hand which could mean a level in some case.

These words are very old but still popular in Go, martial art or video games.

Comment: I've seen 중수/하수 used only in the context of e-sports.  They may be used in some other cases, but they are newly invented words following the pattern of 고수, and some people might even object that they aren't "real words".  Actually, if you ask an ordinary Korean what is 중수/하수 without any context, their first guess is likely to be "heavy water (중수)" and "sewage (하수)".

Comment: @jick  I am a native korean. 고/중/하 mean high/mid/low. They have been used for long time. 수 doesn't mean water. 수 mean a hand which could mean a level in some case. Especially, In Go(board game) or Martial Art, when people want to roughly make classes, they use this word.

Comment: Just checked Naver dictionary and found 하수 is actually in the dictionary.  Sorry for the wrong comment.  (However, I couldn't find 중수 - I still think the word is used only in some circles, but it's possible I'm just old-fashioned.)

Comment: @jick http://krdic.naver.com/user.nhn?docid=e8472b72b57b6c6bfa91e34f1acf7bd1

Comment: @jick Actually, 중수 is more used than 하수.  humble people who are actually 초고수 always say " I am just 중수 " lol

Comment: "이 단어는 이용자들이 직접 참여하여 작성하였습니다." : I'm OK with people using the word 중수 in some contexts, after all, that's how the language evolves.  I'm just saying it's not a *traditional* word: its status is the same as those words like noob, lol, TLDR, etc.

Comment: @jick Not really. 하수 중수 고수 are used in the same area. They are more like spoken languages. It is not like noob, lol and so on. They are very traditional. In Go or Chess or any sports,  they are used by old people. Also in video games, they are also used by young people but I don't think young love those words more than old people because they have their own words like 초보, 신, 프로... (but 고수 should be still popular for sure)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Sung's great answer, there is no word in Korean (as far as I know) that describes "somebody that tries very hard, but doesn't do so well." other than "(아무리) 노력해도 안되는 사람".

[아무리](http://endic.naver.com/krenEntry.nhn?sLn=kr&entryId=37c05bee092b47478b25b8184296fb24&query=%EC%95%84%EB%AC%B4%EB%A6%AC) is an adverb which works as an intensifier and you can drop it when you don't want to emphasize it.

For example: 세상에는 아무리 (열심히) 노력해도 안되는 사람들이 많아. 
             There are many people who can't make it no matter how much (hard) they try.

I don't think there is a word that can replace "노력해도 안되는 사람" in the above example.

As @jick commented, 중수 and 하수 are not very popular, though they will make perfect sense in some contexts.

"초보자" is the word for a beginner and the slang term is "초짜".